Can not initialize NestJS websocket
I'm trying to setup a websocket in my nestjs application. env and package versions are the as the following:
Node: v18.17.0
@nestjs/core: "^9.0.0"
@nestjs/platform-socket.io: "^10.3.8"

And I have create multiple files to implement:
chat.gateway.ts:
import {
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayInit,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(4040)
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnModuleInit {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');

  onModuleInit() {
    this.logger.log('ChatGateway Module has been initialized');
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('newMessage')
  handleMessage(@MessageBody() body: any): void {
    this.logger.log(`Message received: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
    this.server.emit('message', body);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server): void {
    console.log('WebSocket server initialized');
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]): void {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket): void {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}

chat.gateway.module.ts:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatGateway } from './chat.gateway';

@Module({
  providers: [ChatGateway],
})
export class ChatGatewayModule {}

app.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    ...otherModules,
    ChatGatewayModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private readonly logger: LoggerService) {
    mongoose.set('debug', (collectionName: any, method: any, query: any, doc: any) => {
      logger.info(`Mongoose: ${collectionName}.${method}(${JSON.stringify(query)}, ${JSON.stringify(doc)})`);
    });
    this.logger.log("App is running...");
  }

  private onApplicationShutdown(signal: string) {
    this.logger.log("App is shutting down...");
  }
}

And I have create a simple HTML file to check the connection:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WebSocket Test</h1>
  <script>
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4040/chat');

    socket.onopen = function(event) {
      console.log('WebSocket connection established');
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello Server!' }));
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log('Message from server:', event.data);
    };

    socket.onclose = function(event) {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I'm running the nestjs app by running npm run start:dev on my local. It prints LOG [ChatGateway] ChatGateway Module has been initialized, but doesn't print WebSocket server initialized which is in the afterInit method.
Then I tried the connection on the HTML page by using Google Chrome, it fails with WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4040/chat' failed: message.
What should I do to fix?
Thanks.

If you want to access a certain route like ws://localhost:4040/chat (which is called a namespace in websockets terms), you need to change your
@WebSocketGateway(4040)

to
@WebSocketGateway(4040, { namespace: 'chat' })

As for why afterInit() does not work, I found another post that could be useful.
tl;dr: I think you should either upgrade the nestJS core library to 10.3.8 or downgrade your @nestjs/platform-socket.io to 9.0.0 (your core nestJS library). So basically both should be of the same version.
